# Salesforce integration With MYOB Step - by - step

Tags: integration

We are currently trying for the integration of salesforce with MYOB accounting software.
We need to know whether any free app available. if not please guide me with the step by step integration process. Thanks in advance

Regards,
saran

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the AppExchange, a simple search for MYOB got me on the following package:

[Frizby - Order to Invoice](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008ajWPEAY)

> - Syncronize with accounting systems including:
> - Quickbooks
> - MYOB
> - Saasu
> - Xero

As for the step by step explanation, this isn't a get-your-work-done-for-free community, please read the [FAQ](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq) to see what questions are welcome

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. **If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.**

Comment: Hi PJC, 
   Thanks for the Reply. Sure will do as per the community protocol.